# Nginx Wordpress Subdir + wp admin

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I know there are other similar to this thread, but I already tried for days and can not get this through, currently, with the below nginx configuration on Ubuntu 18

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html/wordpress/public_html;
        index index.php index.html;
        server_name "example.com";

    access_log /var/log/nginx/SUBDOMAIN.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/SUBDOMAIN.error.log;

 location /blog {
         index index.php index.html index.htm;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                     include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                     fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
    }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                     deny all;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
                     log_not_found off;
                     access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                     allow all;
                     log_not_found off;
                     access_log off;
       }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                     expires max;
                     log_not_found off;
       }}
```

Here is my folder current structure

- /var/www/html/wordpress/public_html -> include folder blog and one simple index.html (not serving wordpress)
- /var/www/html/wordpress/public_html/blog -> is my wordpress files location

However, there are two wrong parts I need to solve it.

1. It display "mysite.com/blog" okay but when i click on any blog or url -> it shows " example.com/?p=1"  and therefore leads the to simple index.html at location / (" example.com")
2. I can not access to wp-admin also, it will redirect to this if i put "example.com/blog/wp-admin" -> "http://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fblog%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1 -> then 404

Thank you so much.

**Update 2:**
I tried changing the WP_SITEURL to example.com AND WP_HOME to example.com/blog also modified these 2 records in mysql wp-options table.
however, when i tried access /blog/wp-admin -> http://example.com/blog/wp-admin/example.com/blog/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fblog%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1 -> 404

Comment: You need to properly set up `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` WordPress configuration parameters; you can start reading from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857114/difference-between-wp-siteurl-and-wp-home).

Comment: I have tried the above, the 1st issue is solved but the 2nd issue, wp-admin is still not accessible. Do you have any ideas? @IvanShatsky Thank youu.

Comment: updated in the post

Comment: Why `/blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args;` and not just a `/blog/index.php?$args;`? Can't this redirect come from the browser cache? Can you try from the incognito browser window?

Answer (score 0):

For sure you need

```
root /var/www/html/wordpress/public_html/blog;
```

in the block `location /blog {}`

Moreover the block `location ~ \.php$` should looks like below:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
```

also, you need to change try_files directive to
`try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;`